# Why I can use classes from libraries which are not directly added in project.json (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have three layers in my app: `Repositories -> Services -> Web`. Repositories and Services are created as an 'Class Libary (package)' in VS 2015 (this application should run also on OSX/Linux that's why I have to create that kind of library). I addedd dependency in Services to Repository. Here is part of project.json in Services:

```
   "dependencies": {
      "App.Repositories": ""
  },
```

And I added dependency in Web to Services. Here is part of project.json in Web (MVC6):

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "App.Services": ""
  },
```

Thanks to this I can write code like that in Services:

```
using App.Repositories;

namespace App.Services
{
    public class Service
    {
        public Service()
        {
            var repository = new Repository();
            repository.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is ok, because "reference" between projects exists. However I can also use classes placed in Repositories in Web, like that:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using App.Repositories;

namespace App.Web.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        public ValuesController()
        {
            var repository = new Repository();
            repository.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is it normal behaviour in ASP.NET Core 1?
2. How to prevent using classes from Repositories in Web (or general between not directly added libraries)?

Comment: Interesting issue, never realized it as a problem, but that may be because I am used to have references to it in the web application (you need reference to all the assemblies for the dependency injection setup). Thing is, there are no traditional references as in old projects. ASP.NET Core has dependencies, which uses nuget packages and thus all dependencies are "referenced" automatically. One of the reasons is that ASP.NET Core is modularized and has no runtime anymore, so all assemblies required to run the applications are always published together with the app for side-by-side execution

Comment: References only work well if you know the assembly is available on the system (or you provide it as part of the application when you publish it), but then you need to make sure to provide it during publishing. In theory you could use `"frameworks":{"dnx50":{"frameworkAssemblies":{"App.Repositories":""}}}` to create a reference that's not an assembly, but this won't work too well, as dnx (which provided a runtime) is deprecated and will be replaced with dotnet-cli which gets all runtime packages from nuget feed, so there is no "runtime" anymore

Comment: Yes for me it is a issue, because how then divide big enterprise application  into layers? I want to prevent using repositories (event by mistake) into a controllers (for example). It's important when you have a few teams and a lot of developers.

Comment: @mczachurski A little comment is too small for this, but... The software engineering world is slowly turning away from these N-tier big enterprise applications in favor of microservices architectures with well defined bounded contexts (think DDD and messaging architectures). ASP.NET Core is prove of this evolution. If you insist on pursueing this big multi-layered enterprise app, then you're better off using ASP.NET 4.6. Nothing wrong with that! Just saying.